# How to implement Bayeux Protocol in iOS Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am doing a interactive iPad app where there will be a scenario when my app will be opening in multiple iPad devices at the same time,and they can join a group photo share, where one user selects a photo of his choice and that selection will be seen live by other users in their devices too who are joined to same group.

I have just got to know that this kind of behaviour can be achived through Bayeux Protocol using Javascript,Dojo for Web application. So, is there any framework that can achieve this feature in iOS platforms or is anyone know how to integrate Bayeux Protocol  in xcode.
I have no idea about it, so any help and suggestions will be appreciated so that i can atleast get started with this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about Bayeux Protocol and implementation details.

For stuff like that, such as connecting people that use the same app on similar device, and share their actions and so on, I think that considering [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008303) (even if you application is not a game, as you still connect people that will use the application on different devices at the same time, and actions of one user will be refered on other user's devices) might be a good option.

See for example the `GKPeerPickerViewController` to connect users to each others, the [GKTank](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918) example and so on.

Comment: I will look forward to it. But i am voting you for suggestion. If i get the solution from your suggestion, then i will accept your answer too. Thanx @AliSoftware